# Arranging time series data without time stamps based on column condition:

Tags: python, excel, pandas, time-series, finance

I am working on a financial data in which time stamp is absent, so I have data for each day in a random order. The data sheet is for a bank agent, with transaction amount, transaction type(withdrawal, donation), agent's balance before and after transaction.

The data looks like this:
[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlPL3.png)

For each day the data is arranged in descending order of 'prev_bal'. I hope to use the relationship between prev_bal and post_bal to arrange the data set correctly. The value of post_bal for nth transaction is equal to the value of prev_bal for (n+1)th transaction.

For e.g.

Transaction 1: prev_bal = 100, post_bal = 300

Transaction 2: prev_bal = 200, post_bal = 600

Transaction 3: prev_bal = 300, post_bal = 200

My code is like this but, I am getting correct result only for the first day

```
date_list = []
k=0
date_list = pd.to_datetime(df3['date']).dt.date.unique().tolist()
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'PARTY_ID', 'TRANSFER_ID', 'SERVICE_NAME', 'TRANSFER_STATUS',
       'TRANSACTION_AMOUNT', 'COMMISSION', 'SERVICE_CHARGE', 'prev_bal',
       'post_bal'])
for date in date_list:
  mod = df3[df3['date'].dt.date==date] 
  n = mod.index[0]
  time_stamps = len(mod.columns)
  dfx = mod.loc[[n],:]
  res = res.append(dfx)
  for w in range(0,time_stamps):
    a = res.iloc[-1, 9]
    for t in range(0,time_stamps):
      if(a == mod.loc[n+t,'prev_bal']):
        temp = mod.loc[[n+t],:]
        res = res.append(temp)
        break
```

In general, I want an output like this

```
date       SERVICE_NAME      TRANSACTION_AMOUNT    prev_bal     post_bal
2020-02-01 Cash Deposit           200                 100          300
2020-02-01 Cash Withdrawal        100                 300          200   
2020-02-01 Cash Deposit           400                 200          600
```

Comment: From your data, it looks like if you sort the TRANSFER_ID by ignoring the first two characters (Acronym for SERVICE_NAME?) for a particular PARTY_ID, you will get what you want for multiple dates (because 1st field is date and 2nd field is time in TRANSFER_ID).  You can do it in Excel without Python.

Comment: Thanks Oliver!! Awesome observation